# C# AWS Lambda functions exception handling

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Can c# aws lambda function exception handling be done in a global method or only in each function separately?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to handle problems in all of your functions it might be a good ideia to use a Dead Letter Queue that triggers a exception handling function.

[Dead letter queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dlq.html) (DLQ) is an AWS Lambda feature that stores the messages that triggered the lambda and threw non user handled exceptions.

Then you can setup an [AWS Simple Notification](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/sns/) Topic to listen to this queue and trigger a second lambda function that handles your global errors.

It is easier done than said, haha. I recommend trying it.

You can use this [Robust Serverless Application Design](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/compute/robust-serverless-application-design-with-aws-lambda-dlq/) post as a guide.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: No, neither the Lambda runtime or .Net Core support global exception handlers (ASP.Net Core *does* but that wasn't your question).  This would be an excellent addition to the Lambda runtime for .Net Core, or perhaps as a Lambda Layer.